# Как определить прямые и ломаные движения мыши?

Tags: javascript, mouse-event

Как на Javascript отловить - абсолютно прямые и ломаные движения мыши, исключая кривые.

Comment: по вашему математика это смешно?

Comment: В принципе, интересный вопрос. Если в JS можно каждый короткий промежуток времени собирать координаты курсора в массив, то это действительно математическая, алгоритмическая задачка. Но тогда и теги, и описание нужны поконкретнее.

Comment: Вам принципиально код на JS нужен? Я могу подправить вопрос и написать ответ с описанием алгоритма, а Вы его запрограммируете с учётом конкретной специфики.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик!
Да, необходимо решение JS. Все происходит примерно так - 
При движении мыши в массив пишутся ее координаты, как только мышка останавливается (наверное как-то так: jsfiddle.net/superscript18/dNAty/) делаются некие вычисления, на предмет определения является ли этот набор координат - прямой, ломанной или кривой. Если движения мышкой очень короткое (можно изменить) измерения не делаются. Все это происходти во всем окне браузера.

Comment: А абсолютно прямые движения вообще насколько вероятны, если мышку двигает живой человек? Я могу представить такое, только если курсором управляет программа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin по-моему, очевидно, что нужно учитывать определенную погрешность.

Comment: @AivanF. формулировка "абсолютно прямые" предполагает отсутствие погрешностей. Ну, в рамках того, что пиксели дискретны. Вообще такая задача вполне оправдана, например, когда мы пишем защиту от ботов в браузерной онлайн-игре.

Comment: @NickVolynkin кстати да, интересное применение. Но тогда задача слишком тривиальна.

Comment: Уточните границу между ломаной и кривой. Движение мышки в любом случае даст дискретный набор точек.   Считать их прямой, кривой или ломаной – опираясь на величину угла между очередными 3 точками?

Comment: @Sergiks думаю, автор имел в виду математические ломаные (набор связанных отрезков) и кривые (результат построения непрерывной функции или просто изогнутая линия). В программном, дискретном варианте это будет почти одно и то же, только кривые  будут иметь отрезков больше, но они сами короче.

Comment: @rd2d2 сделал вам простой фиддл: [посмотрите на точки](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/LbwdtukL/), с которым придётся иметь дело в реальности. Попробуйте сами провести прямую. И поясните, пожалуйста, свою позицию насчёт границы между прямой, кривой и ломаной.

Comment: "... Я могу представить такое, только если курсором управляет программа." Все верно, нужно отличить человека и программу, программа двигает в ~80% случаев ломаными движениями а человек только кривыми.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Алгоритм и псевдокод

Здесь у нас будут присутствовать такие сущности: класс `Point`, контейнер `Points`, и переменные его типа: `Input` — хранит все записанные координаты мыши, `Output` — будет хранить точки ломаной (или отрезка, если проведена прямая линия).

К тому же, нам понадобятся функции для нахождения угла между двумя точками `Angle.Find (Point, Point)` и функция нахождения модуля разницы двух углов `Angle.Difference (double, double)`.

Для решения задачи будем проходиться по всем точкам и находить *примерно ровные* отрезки. И да, максимальное отклонение для линии будет в константе `Angle.Eps`.

```
// начало ломаной
Output.Add(Input[0]);
// координаты текущего отрезка
Point begin Input[0];
Point end = Input[1];
// угол для сверки
double angle = Angle.Find(begin, end);
// обработка всех точек
for (int i = 2; i < Input.Length - 1; i++) {
    double currentAngle = Angle.Find(begin, Input[i]);
    if (Angle.Difference(currentAngle, angle) < Angle.Max) {
        end = Input[i];
        //TODO: можно также высчитывать угол по всем точкам отрезка
    } else {
        // сохраняем старый отрезок
        Output.Add(end);
        // создаём новый отрезок
        begin = Input[i];
        end = Input [++i];
        angle = Angle.Find(begin, end);
    }
}
Output.Add(end);
```

В результате, если все точки на одной прямой, `Output` будет содержать только две точки: начало и конец отрезка. Если их больше — линия ломаная. А если у ломаной линии расстояние между точками очень мало — это кривая линия. Проверка на кривую линию может быть достаточно простая:

```
bool crooked = false;
for (int i = 1; i < Output.Length; i++) {
    // функция вычисления расстояния между точками и эпсилон для длины отрезков
    if (Point.Distance(Output[i], Output[i - 1]) < Point.Eps) {
        crooked = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

На всякий случай небольшое уточнение. Я выделил `Angle.Difference` потому, что просто так вычитать углы нельзя — для углов в 1 и 359 градусов разница всего лишь два, а не 358. Её можно определить так:

```
double Angle::Difference (double a, double b) {
    if (a > 270 && b < 90) {// 3*Pi/2, Pi/2, если используете радианы
        b += 360; // 2 *Pi
    } else if (b > 270 && a < 90) {
        a += 360;
    }
    return abs(a - b);
}
```

---

### Рабочая JS-версия

```js
// -- Вспомогательные функции --

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function angleDif(a1, a2) {
    if (a1 > 270 && a2 < 90) {
        a2 += 360;
    } else if (a2 > 270 && a1 < 90) {
        a1 += 360;
    }
    return Math.abs(a1 - a2);
}

function angleFind(p1, p2) {
    return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function distance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}


// -- Инициализация --

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var input = [];
var output = [];
var previous = {x:-64, y:-64};

ctx.fillStyle="#CDBCFF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


// -- Константы --

// Отклонение в градусах, при котором прямая считается ломаной,
// и появляется изгиб.
SMALL_ANGLE = 9;

// Расстояние в пикселях между изгибами,
// меньше которого они считаются резкими.
BEND_DIST = 10;

// Число резких изгибов, при котором ломаная считается кривой.
NEED_BENDS = 5;


// -- Основные функции --

// Обрабатывает событие движения мыши.
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var current = {x:mousePos.x, y:mousePos.y}

    // не сохраняем мусорные точки
    if (distance(current, previous) > 2) {
        previous = {x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y};
        input.push(previous);
        process();
        output.push({x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y});
        drawResult();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
}, false);


// Отрисовывает линию.
function drawResult() {
    if (output.length >= 2) {
        ctx.fillStyle="#CDBCFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(output[1].x, output[1].y);
        for (var i = 2; i < output.length; i ++) {
            ctx.lineTo(output[i].x, output[i].y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}


// Выбирает точки для отрисовки и определяет тип линии.
function process() {
    if (input.length < 2)
        return;

    // по этим двум точкам определяется текущее направление линии
    var begin = input[0];
    var last = null;

    // текущая точка
    var current;

    // текущее направление линии
    var angle = 0;
    // направление к текущей точке
    var curAngle = 0;

    // количество резких изгибов
    var bends = 0;

    // список точек для отрисовки
    output = [];
    output.push(begin);

    for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
       current = input[i];

       if (!last) {
            if (distance(begin, current) > 2) {
                last = current;
                angle = angleFind(begin, last);
            }
            continue;
        }

        curAngle = angleFind(begin, current);

        // находим угол последнего изгиба
        if (angleDif(angle, curAngle) < SMALL_ANGLE) {
            // если угол мало меняется, то перейти
            // к следующей точке
            last = current;

        } else {
            // если угол большой при малом расстоянии,
            // то вероятно, что у нас кривая
            if (distance(begin, current) < BEND_DIST) {
                bends += 1;
            }

            // если угол большой, то у нас не прямая
            // нужно добавить новую точку
            output.push(last);
            begin = current;
            last = null;
        }
    }

    // убрать "Прямая" если много точек
    if (output.length > 1) {
        // можно менять число перегибов нужное для кривой
        if (bends >= NEED_BENDS) {
            answer.innerHTML = "Кривая!";
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML = "Ломаная!";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {background-color:#FFF}
#myCanvas {border:1px solid #999}
```

```html
<div id="answer">Прямая!</div> 
<p>Проведите мышкой внутри этого прямоугольника:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за проделанную работу!
Все вроде как работает, но непонятно почему линии рисуются ломаными, нужно постараться что бы стала кривая. Тут не должно быть никаких границ. Человек не может двигать мышкой ломано, всегда получается кривая, а вот машина может. Если вам не сложно, сделайте пожалуйста правки в скрипте.

Comment: Всё упирается в два коэффициента: максимальная разность углов `if (angleDif(angle, curAngle) < 8)` и максимальное расстояние `if (distance(begin, current) < 4)`. Для задачи отделения человека от бота подойдут 6 и 8; можно ещё чуть уменьшить первое и увеличить второе числа, исходя из Ваших конкретных условий.

Comment: Хмм..Пробовал изменить углы, все равно получается ломаная, особенно если быстро двигать мышкой.

Comment: А если подставить `if (angleDif(angle, curAngle) > 20)`?